# nuitka: how to use --include-plugin-files?

Tags: python, pygame, nuitka

I'm trying to compile a very simple pygame script using nuitka.
This is the script (main.py)

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 72)

text = font.render("Hello World", True, (0, 128, 0))

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            done = True

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(text,
        (320 - text.get_width() // 2, 240 - text.get_height() // 2))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

First I tried compiling it with:
`python3 -m nuitka --standalone main.py`
which led to all of these warnings (but finished):

```
Nuitka:WARNING:Use '--plugin-enable=numpy' for: numpy support.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenGL/plugins.py:38' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include-plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py:453' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include-plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py:366' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include-plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py:865' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include-plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py:923' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include-plugin-files'.
```

When running the resulting binary, a black window opens, which then crashes with:

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxxx/git/sesyn/paradigm10123/main.dist/pygame/pkgdata.py", line 51, in getResource
  File "/home/xxxxx/git/sesyn/paradigm10123/main.dist/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in resource_exists
  File "/home/xxxxx/git/sesyn/paradigm10123/main.dist/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1404, in has_resource
  File "/home/xxxxx/git/sesyn/paradigm10123/main.dist/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1473, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So I modified the getResource function where it crashed to print out the files it tries to load. I then added these files via the `--include-plugin-files` command:
`python3 -m nuitka --standalone main.py --include-plugin-files=/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygame/pygame_icon.bmp --include-plugin-files=/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygame/freesansbold.ttf` but running the resulting binary yields the exact same crash.

I also tried adding the OpenGL directory as plugin-dir and used the numpy plugin (I'm not aware of any numpy usage here, but hey, I figured it wouldnt hurt)

`python3 -m nuitka --standalone main.py --include-plugin-files=/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygame/pygame_icon.bmp --include-plugin-files=/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygame/freesansbold.ttf --include-plugin-directory=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenGL/ --enable-plugin=numpy` (which takes roughly 30minutes to compile by now) but the resulting binary still produces the exact same crash. Does anyone know how to make this run?

Oh and btw I'm using the system python on Ubuntu 19.10

```
$ python3 -c "import pygame"
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
$ python3 -m nuitka --version
0.6.7
Python: 3.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2019, 09:21:52) 
Executable: /usr/bin/python3
OS: Linux
Arch: x86_64
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```